# how the linux detects the protocol of the network?

Tags: linux, networking, protocol-buffers

i shaw the following code in linux:

```
void print_ethernet_header(unsigned char* buffer)
{
struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)buffer;
fprintf(logfile , "   |-Protocol  : %x \n",eth- 
>h_proto);
}
```

and as expected it showed the result mentioning the protocol at output screen: 0800H for ip protocol type.

some more code here:

```
sock_raw = socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));
//some code here...
data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , bufsize , 0 , 
(struct sockaddr*)&saddr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
```

Here i am unable to understand that how line: "eth-
>h_proto", picked the correct protocol, because h_proto is just a member of the structure:

```
struct ethhdr{
unsigned char h_dest[ETH_ALEN];
unsigned char h_source[ETH_ALEN];
_be16         h_proto;
}
```

and this structure is mentioned in the inculde lib file in linux system.

i want to know that how "eth->h_proto" picks the correct protocol, is it an inner implemented system code or code written some where else?

Answer (score 0):

The protocol is just part of the payload of the MAC Header. The struct is just `extracting` this data from the raw ethernet header.

References:

- [EtherType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType)
- [Ethernet Frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame)